Incompatible Uncrustify code formatter and code style checker
In Visual Studio Code I use Zachary Flower's Uncrustify formatter extension for C++. And I use ament_cmake_uncrustify for checking code style. The formatter and the checker use the same uncrustify.cfg file. Yet they're not compatible with each other.
The formatter removes spaces around template angle brackets:
using SyncPolicy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<ImageMsg, ImageMsg>;
                                                                  ^^                 ^

But the checker requires spaces:
using SyncPolicy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime < ImageMsg, ImageMsg >;

And the formatter adds a space
class SomeNode : public rclcpp::Node
              ^

where the checker requires
class SomeNode: public rclcpp::Node

Already have been playing around with some sp_xxx_angle parameters, but couldn't really get it right. How do I fix this? I prefer the formatter style. Thanks in advance.
